# Wrap linq queries with Concat into a method

Tags: c#, linq

I have a code that I want to wrap into a method so I can get `results` as an output from it. Call in another method for example `var NewVariable = GetMyJoinedResult();` to run code below.

I have tried with `public static IEnumerable<string> GetMyJoinedResult()` but as currently objects are anonymous code will not even compile.

What type of `public static "??" GetMyJoinedResult()` should I use for that kind of procedure?

Here is my current code:

```
        var t1 = ConnectAndRetriveDatatatable1();
        var t2 = ConnectAndRetriveDatatatable2();

        var firstPart = from table1 in t2.AsEnumerable()
                        join table2 in t1.AsEnumerable()
                            on (string)table1["SNAME"] equals (string)table2["SNAME"] into temp
                        from table2 in temp.DefaultIfEmpty()
                        select new
                        {
                            NRO = (string)table1["NRO"],
                            NRO1 = table2 != null ? (string)table2["NRO"] : string.Empty,
                            SNAME = (string)table1["SNAME"],
                        };

        var secondPart = from table2 in t1.AsEnumerable()
                         join table1 in t2.AsEnumerable()
                             on (string)table2["SNAME"] equals (string)table1["SNAME"] into temp
                         from table1 in temp.DefaultIfEmpty()
                         where table1 == null
                         select new
                         {
                             NRO = string.Empty,
                             NRO1 = (string)table2["NRO"],
                             SNAME = (string)table2["SNAME"],
                         };

        var results = firstPart.Concat(secondPart);
```

Comment: have you tried `public static object GetMyJoinedResult()` ? Or `IEnumerable<object>`? Or `dynamic`?

Comment: @viveknuna `dynamic` worked! Thank you! Can be added as an answer

Comment: As mentioned in my answer you preferably should use classes and stay away from dynamic if possible. C# is a strongly typed language so try to use it :)

Comment: @hatman why you unaccepted the answer? You said it worked for you

Comment: @viveknuna after testing method with using `dynamic" it worked for some cases (with foreach loop in place for getting values out of list but not for further linq queries). However I had to test Ruben-J's olution and it was more robust so I have used it in my code.

Comment: @hatman I have also suggested you the same solution that you can have model class. by the way its ok

Comment: @viveknuna Ruben's answer was more detailed so I have picked it. I would have picked both as an answers, but unfortunately it is not possible. However I think if anybody will find this post sometimes in the future, both answers are good and worth trying (as dynamic worked as well). I understand that this website gives benefits also for your career, but I think that the most important thing is that by asking and answering we are building unique database with valuable information for other people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use a class if this result is always the same

```
public class YourResult{
 public string NRO {get;set;}
 public string NRO1 {get;set;}
 public string SNAME {get;set;}
}
```

You can then use

```
select new YourResult
{
     NRO = string.Empty,
     NRO1 = (string)table2["NRO"],
     SNAME = (string)table2["SNAME"],
};
```

And something like:
`public static IEnumerable<YourResult> GetMyJoinedResult()`

Answer (score 1):

You have may options to solve your issue.

`public static object GetMyJoinedResult()` Or I`Enumerable<object>` Or `dynamic`.

You can create a class and return its object also.

```
public class Data
{
    public string NRO { get; set; }
    public string NRO1 { get; set; }
    public string SNAME { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Returning an object or dynamic isn't a solution in this case is my opinion.